# ubuntu 16.04 internal error /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg

Tags: 16.04, graphics, xorg

I keep getting this error messages when I restart my computer and when I start from complete shut down I get a warning saying "Your screen, graphics card and input device settings could not be detected correctly". Beside all of the messages the computer appear to work fine.

[Picture of the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri2Je.png)

Comment: If the system works fine besides, you might just want to report a bug and fill in an error description explaining what you did when the error occurred. This will hopefully lead to the error being fixed for everyone in time.

Comment: The important part of the error message is shown at the bottom of the dialog which isn't visible. Unfortuanately, the developers of the `apport-gtk` haven't manage to implement my very easy and useful suggestion to make the information copyable since I suggested it some years ago, so if you want to provide the information here you'll have to copy it by hand.